# JLabel icon not imported correctly on Java with Maven project

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am making a project on the GUI library system. My IDE is  Netbeans. Before I was setting Jlabel icon images from external folders but I want the images to be loaded from the project folder so I imported the images to my project folder from NetBeans 'import to project' option. When i compiled the program it shows 'NullPointerException' in Jlabelxxx.setIcon(). This means it is not loading images from my package/folder. I know what null pointer exception is :). My code is totally fine but I don't know why images are not loading from the project folder.

I am using Netbeans GUI for making Jswing design. My directory structure is shown below:

[image]

Project absolute path: C:\Users\nisha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LibraryManagementSystem

Images absolute path: C:\Users\nisha\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LibraryManagementSystem\src\main\java\gpjlibrarymanagementsystem\icons

I have 2 packages in the "LibraryManagementSysten" project folder. Below it i have 3 packages "" "gpjlibrarymanagementsystem" "gpjlibrarymanagementsystem.icons". The default package has nothing. The second one has JFrame files and the last one have images. Please watch the image posted above to understand my directory structure.

I have tried to make different directories in the same project but it's not working.

Examples of code where I am getting 'NullPointerException':

```
    lblMinimize.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-minus-24.png")));

    lblMaximize.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-maximize-button-20.png")));

    lblClose.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-multiply-24.png")));
```

You can see, as per my directory structure, my code is right.

Comment: Stack Trace is here: https://imgur.com/a/RFcoGOk

Comment: Your tree image seems to indicate that the directory is `icon`, not `icons`.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem. The images should be added to the resources folder which is: **yourprojectname\src\main\resources**. In my case: **LibraryManagementSystem\src\main\resources\icons**. All image files are in icons folder :)

In maven the file structure should look like this:

```
> Project |-- pom.xml `-- src
>     `-- main
>         `-- resources
```

However, all your resources may not be in src/main/resources. Thus, you'd have to specify those directories by adding the following to your POM.

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

So if your resources reside in src/my-resources

```
Project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- my-resources
```

you can specify that directory by doing the following:

```
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
```

Furthermore, you can have several directories by adding multiple  elements:

```
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource1</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource2</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>resource3</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
```

Comment: I added the resource but it still fails for me. Any other way to do this?
I have my images on the source directory base path. and can even see the main.png in /target/classes. But somehow Icon.class.getResource(path); fails for me.
Path here is = /images/main.png

Answer (score 0):

One or more of:

```
/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-minus-24.png
/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-maximize-button-20.png
/gpjlibrarymanagementsystem/icons/icons8-multiply-24.png
```

is wrong (the file does not exist), hence `getResource` returns `null`.

Comment: You can see it here: https://imgur.com/a/zJCl2WH I have imported all the images and setted it from netbeans :) so how can it be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The project directory name (see below) is `icon` (singular) but the code says `icons` (plural).

[image]

Comment: No, its actually icons...Netbeans is not showing the last word

Comment: No! And stop posting images of stack traces. Instead [edit] the question, paste the entire stack trace, then use code formatting. (Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.)

Comment: See also the edit to my answer, which, despite your assurance, looks like **`icon`** to me!

Comment: After reading your comment I looked package name thrice and its still icon. For your assurance, I snipped an image: https://imgur.com/a/SKUrmwJ

Comment: It is happening with maven projects only. This man also got the same "NullPointerException": http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-commits/201907.mbox/%3CJIRA.13244116.1562767804000.616308.1562768100117@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I was suffering this changes.</sup>

I was using Packages... the package with icon `Open.png` was `bz.usedPictures`

```
button.setIcon(
  new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
    getClass().getResource("/bz/usedPictures/Open.png")
  )
);
```

I was migrating to maven.

According to Maven:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

`src/main/resources`: `Application/Library resources`

Then I put the ICON in this Location:

```
PROJECTNAME\src\main\resources\usedPictures\
--Open.png
```

**Clean and Build.** And you can check here the location where the file will be get....

```
PROJECTNAME\target\classes\usedPictures\
--Open.png
```

Now the Example using the ICON:

```
button.setIcon(
    new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("usedPictures/Open.png")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in a folder called "resources", the path should be:
src / main / resources / image.jpg

Now in Netbeans click on "Clean and Build Project"

Create a label and with the help of the IDE put an icon, for that go to the label properties.

Once this is done, right click on the label and click on "Custom code" and put in a "try catch" the part where the icon is placed on the label.

It worked for me and it took me a day to figure out how to do it.